# Bash error on opening the terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, games, bashrc

Whenever I open terminal in Ubuntu I get the following bash and I don't know how to solve it. I need a solution as soon as possible:

```
bash: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games")
bash: /home/kaustubh/.bashrc: line 6: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `}'
bash: /home/kaustubh/.bashrc: line 118: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Answer (score 1):

A script that is executed automatically when you start a shell seems to be broken. Based on your error message, it seems like it is `.bashrc`. Are you setting your $PATH in there? It seems like a `}` is missing in that statement.

Comment: yeah before installing android sdk ubuntu used the following commands to setup the path using following command :-  export PATH=$[PATH]:-/android-sdk/tools and export PATH=$[PATH]:-/android-sdk/tools/platform-tools

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem for few days and I could solve it with this code in a terminal:

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~
```

Try this, maybe it will solve yours too.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark this question answered.

Comment: This is dangerous, it will overwrite the users' existing `.bashrc` file.  At a minimum you should explain what this command does, not just say "try this".